# Laravel Eloquent data Relationship issue

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have two tables: 
Students Table:

```
columns: id | family_id | name | class | section
```

Families Table:

```
columns:  id | f_name | f_profession
```

**what i want:** i want to fetch list of brothers and sisters for each student if there is any in student table. i want to show list of brothers/sisters on each student profile.

**what i tried:** i am able to get list of all students, when i click on student name it opens student profile, but doesn't show brothers/sisters of that student.

**My Controller:**

```
public function show($id){
$showdata = Student::find($id);
return View('students.profile' ,compact('showdata');}
```

**My Student Model:**

```
class student extends Model
    {
     public function family() {
      return $this->belongsTo(family::class,'family_id'); }

    public function getSiblings() {
        return $this->family->students;
    }}
```

**My profile View:**

```
Brother Sisters :{{$showdata->getSiblings()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a 'has many through' relationship.

```
public function studentSiblings() {
     return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Sibling', 'App\Family);
    }
```

More information can be found: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: A more appropriate function name would be `siblingStudents` since it's a relationship function.

Comment: @user10341554 but i don't have sibling model? app\sibling??

Comment: @apokryfos i i don't have any model name, siblings, can you please correct my model/view/controllers?

Comment: Error: "Class 'App\Sibling' not found", what should be in siblings?

Comment: It should be `App\Student`. A student has many students via family is how it would read

Comment: @iMatti have you put `use App\Sibling;` at the top of your file? If you don't have a sibling model you will need to create one.